# SSAS Partitions, how many is too many

Tags: ssas, partitioning

I am adding partitions to my SSAS cube, and I want to know if there is a number of partitions to stay under? How many is too many, is the best practice limit at 20 or 200? Does anyone have any real world knowledge they can share?

Comment: I found a good article here:  http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1554201&seqNum=2 that answers my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [another article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140228063441/http://duncansutcliffe.wordpress.com:80/2010/10/15/handling-and-tuning-really-large-analysis-services-cubes/) (by Duncan Sutcliffe) with a section on partitioning.

Also, you will want to consider the overhead requried for managing different partitioning strategies.  If you end up with a lot of partitions, it can be a really P.I.T.A. to manage and so you will probably want to implement some sort of SSIS/Script solution to automate the process of creating partitions.

What you ultimately decide to do will be environment-specific, but between the article you posted and the one by Duncan (above) you should have a pretty good (high-level) idea of the considerations to factor into the decision and which levers are at your disposal.

Comment: Great article. I'm moving into the SSIS space now so that should be fun.

Comment: link is now dead :(

Comment: I replaced the link with the archive.org one, try again ;)